# jQuery :contains selector to search for multiple strings

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, contains

Assuming i have:

```
<li id="1">Mary</li>
<li id="2">John, Mary, Dave</li>
<li id="3">John, Dave, Mary</li>
<li id="4">John</li>
```

If i need to find all <li> Elements which contain "John" and "Mary", how would i construct the jQuery?

A search for a single string seems easy:

```
$('li:contains("John")').text()
```

I am looking for something like the following pseudo code:

```
$('li:contains("John")' && 'li:contains("Mary")').text()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 134, accepted):

#### Answer

To find `li`'s that have text containing BOTH Mary **AND** John:

```
$('li:contains("Mary"):contains("John")')
```

To find `li`'s that have text containing EITHER Mary **OR** John:

```
$('li:contains("Mary"), li:contains("John")')
```

#### Explanation

Just think of the `:contains` as if it was a class declaration, like `.class`:

```
$('li.one.two').      // Find <li>'s with classes of BOTH one AND two
$('li.one, li.two').  // Find <li>'s with a class of EITHER one OR two
```

It's the same with `:contains`:

```
$('li:contains("Mary"):contains("John")').      // Both Mary AND John
$('li:contains("Mary"), li:contains("John")').  // Either Mary OR John
```

#### Demo

http://jsbin.com/ejuzi/edit

Comment: How could I go about spitting out the contains if I have the strings in an Array? The array will be built from checkbox values so it doesn't have a standard length each time?

Answer (score 8):

#### Answer

The correct syntax would be `$("li:contains('John'),li:contains('Mary')").css("color","red")`

But I found out that if you had many cases to test, jQuery will perform very badly (especially on IE6, I know, it's old but still in use). So I decided to write my own attribute filter.

This is how to use it: `$("li:mcontains('John','Mary')").css("color","red")`

#### Code

```
jQuery.expr[':'].mcontains = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
    result = false;     
    theList = meta[3].split("','");

    var contents = (obj.textContent || obj.innerText || jQuery(obj).text() || '')

    for (x=0;x<theList.length;x++) {
        if (contents.indexOf(theList[x]) >= 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

Comment: add `.toLowerCase()` to `contents` and `theList[x]` to make this case insensitive.

Comment: how would you make it case insensitive?

Comment: Thanks - this was what I wanted in Chrome :
But it was driving me a bit nuts, with three entries it would only match the middle one : 
`$("li:mcontains('John', 'Ringo', 'Mary')").css("color","red");`

After a bit of debugging I found 
` theList = meta[3].split("','");`

a) I was using ',<space>' needed to remove the space eg: ','
b) Split was giving  'John, Ringo , Mary' (note single quotes on the first and last entry) 

Then: 
`$("li:mcontains(John', 'Ringo', 'Mary)").css("color","red");`
did work!!
Happy to be pointed out what I am doing wrong - but that was what I found

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
$('li:contains("John"),li:contains("Mary")')
```

Comment: And jQuery doesn't even index anything twice. So there's an automatic filter and Lazarus' answer really finds four elements.

Comment: Thanks, that is what i was hoping would work, but it doesn't. This selector doesn't return any results. I made a quick try with:
$('li:contains("John")','li:contains("Mary")').text() and all i got back was "". 
Even $('li:contains("John")','li:contains("Mary")').css('font-color','red') didn't seem to work.

Comment: I think your are inserting a `'` in between the two `li:contains`.

Comment: So, even correcting the bogus syntax i had in my tests mentioned above, this will still select all the <li> elements. $('li:contains("John"),li:contains("Mary")').css('color','red')

And this (single quotes separating the selectors): $('li:contains("John")','li:contains("Mary")').css('color','red') doesn't select anything at all.

Comment: Ah... I see what you mean, you only want LI that has *both* pieces of text... hmmmm... I'll need to think about that.

Comment: Oh gosh, this cold really affected my brain. Of course it works like Lazarus says, but i didn't make my question very clear.

I wanted to select only <li> elements, which contain both strings, "John" and "Mary". Is that possible at all?

BTW: this was my first post to stackoverflow and i must say, it works extremely well and blindingly fast.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Exactly Lazarus. Sorry for being a so vague in my Q. Blame it on my cold.

Comment: @Stefan: Answered & explained

Comment: @Stefan  Stack Overflow is your friend :)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy:

```
$("li:contains('John'):contains('Mary')")
```