# Jquery search function using contains

Tags: jquery, search, split, contains

I am trying to create a “jquery search function” and I want to be able to use more than one word to sort the results.

Can someone please show me how to make it work?

This is what I got:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.qid').keyup(function() {  
var keyword = $(this).val().toLowerCase().split(" ");

$(".q").removeClass('show');
$(".q:contains('"+ keyword[0] +"'):contains('"+ keyword[1] +"'):contains('"+ keyword[2] +"'):contains('"+ keyword[3] +"')").addClass('show');
if ($('.qid').val() == '')
{
$('.q').removeClass('show');
}
});

});
```

Comment: @Jacob, asked nine questions, provided no answers and zero-acceptance? **Agreed**, and +1.

Answer (score 2):

Please, read this: [jQuery :contains selector to search for multiple strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416803/jquery-contains-selector-to-search-for-multiple-strings)

I think this takes your questions about the "contains".

Comment: Thanks for the info Cesar :) Tough the problem is only to return all words from the input field.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the jquery selector string by replacing spaces with the contains 
Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('.qid').keyup(function() {   
            var keyword = $(this).val().replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/\s+$|^\s+/g, "");  
            var containsString = keyword;
            $(".q").removeClass('show');
                        containsString = ".q:contains("+containsString+")".replace(".q:contains()","");
            console.log(containsString);
            $(containsString).addClass('show');
            if ($('.qid').val() == ''){
                $('.q').removeClass('show');
            }
        });
});

</script>
```

Test:

```
<div>John Resig</div>
<div>George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom Cybernate Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn</div>


<script>
    var baseText = "John Cybernate"
    var containsString = baseText.replace(" ", " ,div:contains(");
    $("div:contains(" + containsString + ")").css("text-decoration", "underline");
</script>
```

Check the post @: http://www.jsfiddle.net/RUF4P/4/ (Type Lorem Ipsum)

Comment: Thanks Cybernate, this works. But when I typ in "space" after each word the searchfunction removes the class from all divs, and the divs ad hidden... It's a good start!

Comment: My bad, actually it doesn't work. Will try some more and update the question.

Comment: I have updated the post and also posted a link to jsfiddle. Try this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/RUF4P/4/