# Select any TR where a TD's text contains foo

Tags: jquery-selectors

I'm pretty sure this can be done without going into a function but I want to grab any TR where there is a `<td>Mail ...</td>` or `<td>Foo ... </td>` as examples.

I keep thinking it should look like

`$('tr[./text()^="foo"]')` but chrome doesn't like it.
or `$('tr[./td/text()^="Mail"]')` but no luck
can this be done with a simple selector?

Comment: Selectors have to be valid CSS selectors (more or less). But they are not XPath! You cannot do this with a simple selector, but maybe with `filter`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm quite surprised no one came up with this, maybe my question was too vague.

```
$('tr:has(td:contains("Leather"))').hide()
$('tr:has(td:contains("Mail"))').hide()
$('tr:has(td:contains("Cloth"))').hide()
$('tr:has(td:contains("Bow"))').hide()
$('tr:has(td:contains("Gun"))').hide()
```

Going to make it a bookmarklet for searching for armor and weapons for a dk or pally

Comment: Well, as stated in the answers, `:contains` searches for text in any part of the element, while you asked specifically for start with. Also, you can string selectors together with a comma (`,`) so that you won't have to use 5 `$` and `hide()`s

Comment: neat, I was talking about from a :has and overall total solution answer, rather than just pieces of the solution.

Comment: No, your question was too specific.

Comment: For reference a good look at the , option Yi Jiang is talking about : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416803/jquery-contains-selector-to-search-for-multiple-strings/2417076#2417076

Comment: @BoltClock - well no where in the question does it specify starts with, that's just the xpath operators I was trying to use

Comment: @Maslow: The title of your question is *Select any TR where a TD's text **starts** with foo*. And fact is that you cannot do this with a simple selector. As you have the only information about the text, yes, you could have had a look whether the words you are looking for are also contained in the other cells or not.... anyway, at least you have your solution.

Comment: @Felix Kling - ah tunnel vision at the question instead of the title.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly for me: `$('tr:has(td:contains("StatusID:1"))').addClass('CompletedRow');`

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution:

```
$('td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('Foo') === 0;
}).closest('tr');
```

You have to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to work on the element's text (you can't do this with a selector, at least not the way you want to) and [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) should be self explaining.

*Edit: But this could select a `<tr>` elements multiple times. I actually don't know how jQuery handles this. Another solution would be to use two nested `filter`s (on `tr` and on `td` but somehow this feels inefficient).*

*Edit2: From version 1.4.4 on, jQuery seems to be smart enough to deal with multiple occurances of the same element (i.e. it works like a set). **[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/hAcDS/)** (if you change to version 1.4.2, you'll see that the first row gets selected twice).*

Comment: looks like wowhead.com is `This page already using jQuery v1.4.2` so I'll have to deal with the duplication somehow.

Comment: was starts with was a premature optimization on my part? it may not be worth the tradeoff in readability loss to optimize string search

Answer (score 1):

There is "contains:"

`TD:contains("Mail")`

But that just looks for Mail anywhere in the element (there is no 'starts with').

Comment: this may be a great fit based on the tiny scale of my usage. I would like to know ways to accomplish for larger scale or more scalable options if any exist though. going to try this one.

Comment: `$('td:contains("Mail")::ancestor/[td]').hide()` syntax issue but getting very close

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/ is a starts with but it's only for attributes... is the text somehow able to be treated as an attribute?