# How to check two parameters in li:contains method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using this method to change CSS

```
$("#AllProducts li:contains('" + Product + "')").css("background", "white");
```

This works fine, but now I need to check two parameters when I change CSS like below

```
$("#AllProducts li:contains('" + Product + "')&&('" + iCategory + "') ").css("background", "white");
```

However, this doesn't work. I can't check if contains product and then if iCategory, I need them to be in the same object.

Comment: Dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416803/jquery-contains-selector-to-search-for-multiple-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2417076/284538). Short answer, try this:

```
$("#AllProducts li:contains('" + Product + "'):contains('" + iCategory + "') ")
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$("#AllProducts li:contains('" + Product + "'):contains('" + iCategory + "')").css("background", "white");
```