# Jquery to hide table rows depending on multiple values from different columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to hide table rows after checking for accepted values in multiple columns.

The table would be:

```
<table id="my-table>
<tr><td class="name">John</td><td class="lastname">Doe</td></tr>
<tr><td class="name">Ann</td><td class="lastname">Doe</td></tr>
<tr><td class="name">John</td><td class="lastname">Smith</td></tr>
</table>
```

Based on my research so far (and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416803/jquery-contains-selector-to-search-for-multiple-strings)), hiding all but John Doe would require the following Jquery phrase:

```
$("#my-table td.name:not(:contains('John')):td.lastname:not(:contains('Doe'))").parent().hide();
```

But Jquery doesn't like that and says `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: td`

What's the right way to do this?

By the same token I'd like to understand how to make more complex queries such as:
`Hide all rows with 'first name' containing 'a' OR 'b' AND 'last name' containing 'x' OR 'y'`.

Comment: What about changing colon to space in this section `:td.lastname`?

Comment: Yeah i tried that too. In which case I do not get an error message, but cannot see any effect on the table either. So it was an inconclusive test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate on each `tr` instead then check each `first` and `last` `td`.

```
$( "tr" ).each( function( index, val ){
    if($(this).find("td:first-child").text() == 'John' && $(this).find("td:last-child").text() == 'Doe') {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ers1d9n6/)

**Update:** to hide all but John Doe

```
$( "tr" ).each( function( index, val ){
    if($(this).find("td:first-child").text() != 'John'  || $(this).find("td:last-child").text() != 'Doe') {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ers1d9n6/1/)

Comment: Iterating is how I thought it should be done initially, but didn't come across the `.each()` function. I like that :) Do you know of a good reference for practical Jquery use? C3School barely surfaces it.

Comment: PS: how can I break or continue from this Jquery iteration? For instance I want to skip row 0 (the header row).

Comment: And another question if you don't mind: is it better to look for the .text() value of the td's OR should I also add a `content` attribute to them and look up for that attribute's values?

Comment: @Benjamin Regarding skipping the header row, how about putting your header inside `thead`then the other ones inside `tbody` something like [this](http://www.html5-tutorials.org/tables/thead-tbody/). Then on your selector `$("tbody tr")` so it only select `tr` inside `tbody`

Comment: @Benjamin regarding the `.text()`, it really depends on what's inside `td` tag. If it's only the name then yes that means there's no need to do an extra code to get the value on your `content` attribute but, make sure you trim when you use `text()`.

Comment: @Benjamin Also about your first question, no sorry I don't have a specific site for reference other than asking/reading posts on Stackoverflow and also just by googling.

Comment: Great answer anyway, thanks a lot. I think I'll use an attribute because some of my columns will display an icon for certain values, and no text. So i'll still need to search for a 'true' / 'false' hidden in the HTML. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Because `:td` is not a valid pseudo selector. You can use selector `#my-table td.name:not(:contains('John')),#my-table td.lastname:not(:contains('Doe'))`. For **[multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)** you can use `,`.

```js
$("#my-table td.name:not(:contains('John')),#my-table td.lastname:not(:contains('Doe'))").parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td class="name">John</td>
    <td class="lastname ">Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name ">Ann</td>
    <td class="lastname ">Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name ">John</td>
    <td class="lastname ">Smith</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: From the reference you linked to, I understand the comma separator means OR (not AND), but in your example it works as AND. I'm confused about how I can ask either AND or OR. Could you please clarify?