# Jquery refine results of a table: two or more logic statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide values of a table if they match both statements
In my refine() function, the two statements work individually but if they run together whichever runs second takes over,

i want a way to say

if statement a AND statement b are true, do at the same time

```
<html>
    <body>

    <select id="gender" name="gender"> 
    <option value="">Both</option>
    <option value="M">Male</option>
    <option value="F">Female</option>
    </select>

    <select id="region" name="region"> 
    <option value="">All Regions</option>
    <option value="East Midlands">East Midlands</option>
    <option value="Greater London">Greater London</option>
    <option value="Northern Ireland">Northern Ireland</option>
    <option value="North West">North West</option>
    <option value="North Midlands">North Midlands</option>
    <option value="Scotland">Scotland</option>
    <option value="South East">South East</option>
    <option value="South Midland">South Midlands</option>
    <option value="South West">South West</option>
    <option value="West Midlands">West Midlands</option>
    <option value="Yorkshire & North East">Yorkshire & North East</option>
    </select>

    <button id="button" onClick="refine()">Refine Results</button>
    </body>
    </html>

    <script>

    function refine(){

       var gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
       var region = document.getElementById('region').value;

       $('#t01 tbody tr').each(function() {
        $(this).toggle($('td:eq(1):contains(' + gender + ')', this).length > 0);
      })

       $('#t01 tbody tr').each(function() {
        $(this).toggle($('td:not(:contains(' + region + ')', this).length > 0);
      })
    }
    </script>
```

AFTER EDIT:

Imagine this being the table

M Greater London

F Greater London

M North West

F North West

---

If the user selects Male + North West

### it would only show

M North West

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly. This may help you

```
    function refine(){

        var gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
        var region = document.getElementById('region').value;

        $('#t01 tbody tr').each(function() {
            var firstMatch = $('td:eq(1):contains(' + gender + ')', this).length > 0;
            var secondMatch = $('td:not(:contains(' + region + ')', this).length > 0;

            if (firstMatch && secondMatch) {
                $(this).toggle(firstMatch);
                $(this).toggle(secondMatch);
            }
        })
    }
```

If not, be more specific please.

Comment: thanks for responding, this didn't quite work. whoops hit enter, one second as i edit

Comment: updated the question abit, i was looking for something that would put both "'td:eq(1):contains(' + gender + ')', this).length > 0;" and $('td:not(:contains(' + region + ')', this).length > 0) into the same statement, and not putting them into seperate commands, something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2417076/4580396 , however i could not copy the solution