# How to add multiple words in a jQuery contains selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add multiple words in a jQuery contains selector?

The following doesn't work.

```
 let selector = `button:not(:contains('Following', 'Requested'))`;
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery :contains selector to search for multiple strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416803/jquery-contains-selector-to-search-for-multiple-strings)

Answer (score 0):

You don't told us if you want both of words (logical AND) or any of words (logical OR). So I answer for both cases.

In jQuery selectors logical AND is: `:contains(...):contains(...)`, and logical OR is: `:contains(...), :contains(...)`.